# Headings with horizontal lines in google docs?

Tags: header, formatting, styles, documentation

Is there a way to achieve this sort of styling in google docs?

[image: Heading styles]

Have looked everywhere and tried everything I can think of. TIA.

Comment: What is the difference between the 2nd, 4th and 5th except for the color? and maybe the 3rd although it looks like it are 2 color but this is unclear, might be an effect from the png generation.

Comment: @albert I'm not sure, but just want to achieve this basic concept rather than any differences between the examples. If I could get a basic black horizontal line I'd be happy.

Comment: Better to make your requirements clear in the question. Now it is very broad and, as commented, a bit unclear.

Comment: @albert I don't know how it could be any more clear. I want a horizontal line to frame text as in the image. If the differences between the examples mattered I would have elucidated that. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using em-dashes before and after your header:

—————————————————————— MY TITLE —————————————————

In google docs, using an Arial font at least, the line appears continuous.

Answer (score 0):

You could first insert a new drawing, draw a line and then add the next box over the line. You need to make the text box fill white and drag the text box over the line you just drew. This is the only way I found.